# Dual HDD; reinstalled windows and now can't go past boot screen logo

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive, uefi, ssd

So I have a three drive set up. 1 SSD (Windows 7), 1 HDD (Windows 7 storage), 1 HDD (Ubuntu 12.04). I was not thinking and reinstalled Windows and messed it up. If I have the Ubuntu HDD disconnected, then I boot into Windows like normal. If I have the Ubuntu HDD connected, then I get stuck at my motherboard's boot screen logo. I cannot access anything through F2/DEL (UEFI) or F11 (Boot Menu). Because of this, I cannot do anything with the Ubuntu HDD whether it be through UEFI or Windows or even a livecd/liveusb, because with the Ubuntu HDD plugged in, I cannot go past the ASRock boot screen.

Answer (score 0):

The [Boot-Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) tool should help. Please connect both your disks, then run Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair` from a disk (eg Boot-Repair-Disk).

[image]